Get all types of resources in a resource group
with that I can get one line for a reource group my-grp
resourcecontainers
| where resourceGroup contains 'my-grp'

All examples are explicit for resources like vm or disks.
How can I get all type of resources for that particular group?

You can use the following Azure Resource Graph (ARG) query to get all types of resources for a particular resource group.
resources
| where resourceGroup == 'yourResourceGroupName'
| project type


excellent, do you know how to create a visualization from that like in the resource vizualizer ?
